# как убрать номер перед заголовком "Список литературы" в latex

Tags: latex

Я пишу документ сплошным текстом, без использования \chapter, \section, а также без оглавления.
Мне нужен в конце документа только список литературы (источник ссылок - внешний .bib файл). Вот как я его подключаю:

```
\clearpage
\bibliography{autoreferat}
```

Но у меня получается вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта цифра 1 как кость в горле. Она здесь не нужна. Уже несколько часов потратил на поиск в интернете как её убрать. Ничего дельного пока не нашёл. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот преамбула (кажется, так это называется) моего .tex документа:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[figure]{totalcount}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{breqn}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{}
\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.6}

\linespread{1.25}           %-интервал между строками

\righthyphenmin=2 \textwidth = 17cm \oddsidemargin = -.54cm \topmargin = -1.54cm \textheight = 25 cm

\begin{document}
\newtotcounter{citnum}
\def\oldbibitem{} \let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\stepcounter{citnum}\oldbibitem}
\sloppy                             %-выравнивание по правому краю
\sloppy                             %-выравнивание по правому краю
\titlepage
```

Comment: Это? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71129/bibliography-in-table-of-contents

Comment: Да, спасибо. У меня заработало следующее: вместо \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} использовал \usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind} (убрал numbib), и теперь "Список литературы" идёт без номера 1, как мне и нужно.

Comment: Вы можете это написать как ответ на пост, а я помечу Ваш ответ как правильный, если Вам это, конечно, нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tex.stackexchange.com по аналогичной проблеме [советует](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71129/bibliography-in-table-of-contents) использовать tocbibind без опции numbib:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
```